# Armadillo C++: How to modify multiple array elements of a matrix using multiple elements from another matrix, specifically in a cube structure?

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, matrix, armadillo

In MATLAB, if I have two 3x3 matrices A and B and want to copy the last two columns of B into the first two of A, I would use the following syntax:

```
A(:,1:2) = B(:,2:3)
```

I am trying to complete the same action using Armadillo in C++, specifically for a cube structure. In Armadillo, if I had two cubes A and B with nine slices (with each slice being a 3x3 matrix), I assumed I would use the following to perform the same column element update:

```
A(span(0,2),span(0,1),span(i)) = B(span(0,2),span(1,2),span(i))
```

where 'i' is just the slice index. The syntax is based on the Armadillo syntax guide.

The code compiles without error and runs; the cube slices are just not being updated. Am I using the correct Armadillo syntax here, and is this the most efficient way to perform these operations?

Comment: Your code actually doesn't compile. You're using the wrong [subcube](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#subcube) syntax. Replace the `i` with `span(i,i)` or `span::all`.  The first form updates one slice. The second form updates all slices.

Comment: @hbrerkere Ah, that makes sense, thanks. The code was compiling as I had `span(i)` rather than `i` as I had previously specified in the question. I'll update the question to mention that.

Comment: The syntax looks right now. According to my tests, this works. It copies the relevant parts from `B` to `A`. Are you sure there isn't a bug somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @hbrerkere You're correct, that syntax does indeed work. There turned out to be a bug in the code after all; I was using an incorrect index and not all of the elements were being copied, so the syntax was not the problem. I'm glad I asked about the syntax all the same just for clarity. Thanks for your help with this, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple copy/paste (not a shift/rotation of your cube matrices), you can use this syntax that do the trick :

```
#include <armadillo>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t num_slices = 9;

    arma::icube A (3, 3, num_slices);
    arma::icube B (3, 3, num_slices);

    A.zeros();
    B.randn();

    A.print("Cube A :\n");
    B.print("Cube B :\n");

    for (int s = 0; s < num_slices; ++s)
        A.slice(s)(arma::span::all, arma::span(0, 1)) = 
        B.slice(s)(arma::span::all, arma::span(1, 2));

    A.print("Cube A :\n");
    B.print("Cube B :\n");

    return 0;
}
```